# Find the number of way letters a,b,c,d,e that can be arranged in 10 places without repetition, as the letter should be in alphabetical order?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Find the number of way letters a,b,c,d,e that can be arranged in 10 places without repetition, as the letter should be in alphabetical order?

Like we have ten places, _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _.
Arrangements like this,

a b c d e _ _ _ _ _

a _ b c d e _ _ _ _

a _ _b c d e _ _ _ _ 
.

.

.

_ _ _a b _ c _ d e

_ _ _a _ _ b c d e

_ _ _ _a _ b c d e

_ _ _ _ _a b c d e.

Can't be like this,  _ _ _ _ _a  **c b** d e

Answer (score 2):

Choose $5$ spots. There is only $1$ way to put them in alphabetical order. Therefore there are $\binom{10}5=252$ ways.